# Time Machine size explodes when copied to new drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, rsync, dd

I'm trying to replace a 640GB USB2 drive which I use as my Time Machine backup device with a 1TB FireWire 400 drive without losing the current backup history.  Given that the 640GB drive is nearly full and the 400Mbps transfer limit of this combination, I realized that this process could take quite some time and might get interrupted in the middle.  As a result, I decided to try doing it with `rsync` instead of Finder (as [Apple suggests](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380)).  After some false starts and some searching online I settled on the following `rsync` command:

```
rsync -aHXSvPh --hfs-compression --protect-decmpfs /Volumes/Macintosh\ BK/Backups.backupdb /Volumes/Untitled
```

However, this command is still causing significant bloat on the destination drive (to the point where I don't expect the contents of the old drive to fit on the new one, despite the new drive being about 1.5 times larger).  Are there any `rsync` options which I'm missing which would eliminate this bloat (I'm using v3.1.2 protocol version 31)?

It has also occurred to me that perhaps I'm using the wrong tool for the job.  Would a block copy tool like `dd` be more appropriate?  If so, how would I set that up so as to make the process resumable in the event of an interruption (such as one caused by a full system crash, something which happened to me twice while running the `rsync` command)?  I've never used `dd` before and so am unfamiliar with its abilities (but do have access to both the version that comes packaged with Mac OSX and the GNU version 8.25).

Comment: I answered below, but then realized your `rsync` invocation should have preserved hardlinks given the `-H`. Is your destination volume HFS+? If you run `rsync --version` does it list hardlinks in the capabilities statement? What happens if you use the system `rsync` instead of the one you're using?

Comment: Another thought: `-a` implies no `-H`. I wonder if the presence of `-a` is overriding your explicit `-H`.

Comment: I've done this before for similar size backup images.  Just use the Finder, and keep your Mac and drives from going to sleep, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd` doesn't adjust the various volume data structures based on the target volume size, so it's only appropriate if the source and destination volumes are *exactly* the same size. Generally, I recommend `asr` instead, but it doesn't have a good way to continue after a crash.

So, one possibility would be to shrink the target volume to match the source, use `dd` to copy the raw volume, then expand the target back to the full 1TB. I haven't tested this, but I think this is the process you'd need:

1. `diskutil list` will list the volume's device identifiers (e.g. disk2s3 is the third slice (partition) of physical disk #2)
2. `diskutil info <sourcevolumeid>` will list the source volume size in bytes (along with lots of other info)
3. `diskutil resizeVolume <targetvolumeid> <sourcevolumesize>B` (the "B" means "bytes" -- see the "SIZES" section of the `diskutil` man page).
4. `diskutil unmount <sourcevolumeid>` and `diskutil unmount <targetvolumeid>` -- don't use `dd` on mounted volumes!
5. `sudo dd if=/dev/r<sourcevolumeid> of=/dev/r<targetvolumeid>` to do the copy. Note the "r" prefix on the device names -- this bypasses the OS disk buffers, and in my experience makes `dd` run much faster. **Be very careful to get the volume IDs right, or you may copy a blank volume over your backup!**
6. Finally, use either `diskutil resizeVolume` or Disk Utility to expand the target volume out to the full disk's size.

Oh, and a warning: this process assumes neither the source or destination is being managed by Core Storage. If they are (e.g. if they're encrypted), things get a bit more complicated.

Comment: What I've read about `dd` indicates that getting the `bs` argument right can greatly speed up the process.  Obviously, though, I don't want to be testing to determine the right size with the whole volume.  If I were to use something like the scripts [here](http://blog.tdg5.com/tuning-dd-block-size/) or [here](https://github.com/sampablokuper/dd-opt) to determine the optimal value for `bs`, where would I insert that step and would it be necessary to ensure the disks are unmounted during that process?

Comment: I'd do that after dismounting the volumes (i.e. between steps 4 and 5). You can also test with the buffered device (without the "r" prefix), but in my experience that's always significantly slower. Be careful you don't test writing to the source volume!

Comment: This process worked with one modification: After performing step 5, the ownership of the new volume had changed to match the ownership of the Time Machine source volume.  Thus in order to resize the volume I first had to change it's ownership using `chown`.  Once I owned the volume, I was allowed to resize it and could finish the process.

Comment: Is this really true? i swear i've used dd to dump smaller backups onto bigger disks in the past.  But maybe my memory is failing me.

Comment: @deweydb `dd`ing to a larger partition will *sort of* work. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204462/resizing-hfs-volume-after-cloning) for an example of the trouble it can cause.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that Time Machine makes heavy use of hardlinks, which is where one underlying file – one stream of bytes – appears as multiple filenames in multiple directories on the filesystem. If you do a copy that isn't savvy about hardlinks, then that underlying file will get copied multiple times (once for each time it's hardlinked).

So let's say you have a 1GB disk image file, that's been there from the beginning, so it shows up as a hardlink in all of your periodic Time Machine backups, and you have 100 Time Machine backups. If you copy that without being smart about hardlinks, You'll end up with 100 copies of that 1GB file, for 100GB total, instead of just 1GB with 100 hardlinks pointing at it.

I'm sure Apple knows their Finder-copy advice preserved hardlinks properly. I would expect that Disk Utility's "Restore" functionality does as well. Don't let the "Restore" name fool you, it's not just for restoring from backups; it's Disk Utility's way to do a block copy from one volume (or disk image) to another.

**Updated to add:**
Hmm, `rsync -H` should have preserved hardlinks. Are you sure your destination volume is HFS+, or another filesystem that OS X trusts with hardlinks?

Comment: `rsync -H` will preserve hardlinked *files*, but Time Machine also uses hard-linked directories -- that's something most unixes don't support, so I'm pretty sure `rsync` doesn't even contemplate them as possibilities, let alone handle them properly.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That's probably a better answer than mine. Why don't you post that separately and I'll delete mine?

Comment: I'd leave yours -- I'm pretty sure it's correct about the core problem. Also, I just posted an alternate suggestion.

Comment: One of my false starts included leaving off the `-H`, so I know that `rsync` is handling the hardlinked files correctly.  Of course, that doesn't mean anything if the issues is with hardlinked directories as @GordonDavisson suggests.

Comment: Also, I am sure that the volume is HFS+.  Switching the drive filesystem to that was the first thing I did when I got it.