# Is there a way to use the "dd" command to transfer specific folders in an external hard drive?

Tags: macos, backup, dd

I am currently trying to use `dd` to backup and copy the Backups.db folder (which contains all Time Machine Backups for Mac OS) in my external hard drive. The issue is that my hard drive does not only contain the Backups.db folder, rather it also contains other folders and files at the top level. If I use `dd` on the device, it will copy the other folders and files as well. I need to use something like `dd` because of the hard links present in the Backups.db folder, which makes something like `cp` or `tar` not work.

At this point, should I copy out the other top level folders so that the external drive only contains the Backups.db folder? Or is there a more efficient way for this? I am asking as I know `dd` can only be used on devices, after unmounting.

Comment: Please specify that you are using MacOS in title. I was thinking all files in Linux are hard links, just sometimes multiple files pointing to same inode.

Comment: @Ding-YiChen tags should not be added to titles. It is clear enough that this is about macOS (where all files are also hard links, just the same as Linux).

Comment: The GNU versions of `cp` and `tar` (installed via homebrew) can preserve hardlinks and permissions.

Comment: Your using the wrong tool my friend, perhaps rsync would be more appropriate.

Comment: reminder `dd` is known as disk destroyer. be very careful with it.

Comment: What about `rsync`? [ [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) ]

Comment: @OrangeDog are there actual rules say that you cannot put your OS in title? Having put the OS in title will  definitely help the ppl from search engine. That also prevent MacOS noob like me to approach this thread.

Comment: @Ding-YiChen https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/155659

Comment: @OrangeDog It says `it is not necessary to include "tags"`, not forbidden. It also said `the system automatically prepends the most commonly used tag to the question title`, clearly it wasn't the case.

Comment: @Ding-YiChen the title is `macos - Is there a way ...`

Answer (score 12):

To answer the question, **no** it is not feasible.

`dd` operates directly on the blocks of a device, and has no understanding of file systems, folder, or files. A single directory will almost never be stored in a single contiguous region, and even single files may be broken up a spread around. Moreover, you cannot copy only bits of a filesystem to save space and expect it to still work, because all the indexes and offsets still need to line up.

The work required to do such a thing involves writing basically a whole filesystem driver to understand how everything is located and how it can be changed, and performing it with multiple `dd` calls. There's no point when this already exists and can be done with the normal file utilities like GNU `cp`, `tar`, and `rsync`.

Comment: To be precise, `dd` will operate directly on the blocks of a device **or file**. You can copy a file with `dd`. Copying a hierarchy of files, though, is indeed not something `dd` can do, unless all of that is within a single device or file and one wants to copy the whole thing, not parts of it.

Comment: Is there any difference between `cp` and `dd` when used to copy a simple file?

Comment: @Vilx- `dd` can only copy the data, not the metadata (its name, permissions, etc,)

Answer (score 4):

I'd always say, don't try to do from the command line something that can be easily achieved using the GUI.

Copied from [How to copy Mac Time Machine from on drive to another](https://superuser.com/questions/1595813/how-to-copy-mac-time-machine-from-on-drive-to-another)
Finder knows how to do this, almost nothing else does.

Hard links &/or permissions are the downfall usually.
Don't attempt to manually trim it as part of the copy process, just copy the whole lot. If you need to trim by size or date, do it separately.

Apple guide on copying - [Transfer Time Machine backups from one backup disk to another](https://support.apple.com/HT202380)

In brief:
Format HFS+
Set correct permissions `system rw wheel rw everyone r`
Turn off Time Machine
Drag the entire Backups.backupdb folder to the new drive.

Ask Different guide on trimming for size - [Remove unnecessary backups from TimeMachine to get space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86670/remove-unnecessary-backups-from-timemachine-to-get-space)

Comment: are you aware of any ways I can archive the entire Backups.db folder, upload it online, then still be able to run it like nothing happened? thanks

Comment: I'd say it would be impossible. No online structure is going to be able to translate the hard links. You'd end up with a 1TB drive taking up 50TB online.

Comment: @user321627 GNU `tar` can preserve hardlinks, and online storage will not fiddle with it.

Comment: @OrangeDog - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400768/if-i-used-tar-to-archive-time-machines-backups-backupdb-folder-can-the-resulti would agree with you, but no-one ever came back to say it worked.This is now getting so far away from the OP [& my answer] that it ought to be a new question.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, any question would be a duplicate of that one.